# JSON KEY/VALUE to PHP variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing, foreach

I'll get right to the point.

I'm trying to save data retrieved from an API using the following:

```
$i=0;
foreach($results->results as $product){
    $products[$i]['pid']            = $product->listing_id;
    $products[$i]['title']          = $product->title;
    $products[$i]['url']            = $product->url;
    $products[$i]['price']          = $product->price;
    $products[$i]['quantity']       = $product->quantity;
    $products[$i]['endtime']        = $product->ending_tsz;
$products[$i]['thumb']          = $product->results.Images[url_75x75];
```

Here is the JSON request:

```
{
   "count":163,
   "results":[
      {
     "listing_id":118973432,
     "state":"active",
     "user_id":27549667,
     "category_id":68894752,
     "title":"Funny I Love You Valentines Card - I Heart you Even More then a Nerd Loves Starwars - Adult Funny Humor Greeting Cards",
     "description":"You know how much Nerds be loving the Star Wars , this Valentines day show the one you love that you love them even more then that - The perfect greeting card for that special someone!\r\n\r\nGUARANTEED CHRISTMAS DELIVERY - Place your orders by 12\/19 and get it by Christmas Eve - Upgraded Two Shipping available starting at $5, just contact us to upgrade\r\n\r\nDetails:\r\n\r\n- Outside Message: I love you even more then a nerd loves Starwars\r\n- Inside Message: Blank Inside\r\n- Size A7 (5x7)\r\n- Matching White Envelope included \r\n- Packaged in a cello sleeve for protection in transit\r\n\r\nWe will gladly ship to your recipient! Just specify a ship to address and any special message in &quot;notes to seller&quot; at checkout.  Need a Custom Card, Magnet or keychain, we do that too!\r\n\r\nShipping:\r\nUS S&H is $2-Ships within 1 business day. Please allow 2-5 business days for delivery.\r\nIntl S&H is $4 - Ships within 1 business day - Please allow 7-10 business days for delivery.\r\n\r\nBuy MORE and SAVE on shipping! Express shipment is available to most US cities contact us for price and details.\r\n\r\nFor More Rude, crude and downright funny greeting cards, novelty gifts and prints, visit our Etsy store and browse a large selection single cards, greeting card sets, prints and more totally edgy, racy, adult, crass, lude, perverted and all things nasty!\r\nimjustsayininc.etsy.com",
     "creation_tsz":1422565585,
     "ending_tsz":1432929985,
     "original_creation_tsz":1356746393,
     "last_modified_tsz":1422565585,
     "price":"4.00",
     "currency_code":"USD",
     "quantity":3,
     "tags":[
        "funny card",
        "greeting card",
        "novelty card",
        "mature card",
        "adult card",
        "cards",
        "funny cards",
        "relationship card",
        "love card",
        "i love you card",
        "valentines cards",
        "funny valentine",
        "valentines day card"
     ],
     "category_path":[
        "Paper Goods",
        "Cards",
        "Valentine"
     ],
     "category_path_ids":[
        69150367,
        69152963,
        68894752
     ],
     "materials":[
        "Papaer",
        "Ink",
        "Envelope"
     ],
     "shop_section_id":12656719,
     "featured_rank":null,
     "state_tsz":1421921498,
     "url":"https:\/\/www.etsy.com\/listing\/118973432\/funny-i-love-you-valentines-card-i-heart?utm_source=massetsy&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=api",
     "views":764,
     "num_favorers":102,
     "shipping_template_id":null,
     "processing_min":1,
     "processing_max":1,
     "who_made":"i_did",
     "is_supply":"false",
     "when_made":"2010_2015",
     "is_private":false,
     "recipient":"unisex_adults",
     "occasion":"valentines",
     "style":null,
     "non_taxable":false,
     "is_customizable":true,
     "is_digital":false,
     "file_data":"",
     "language":"en-US",
     "has_variations":false,
     "used_manufacturer":false,
     "Images":[
        {
           "listing_image_id":410447372,
           "hex_code":"C1AFB1",
           "red":193,
           "green":175,
           "blue":177,
           "hue":353,
           "saturation":9,
           "brightness":75,
           "is_black_and_white":false,
           "creation_tsz":1356746394,
           "listing_id":118973432,
           "rank":1,
           "url_75x75":"https:\/\/img0.etsystatic.com\/015\/0\/7566894\/il_75x75.410447372_sjo4.jpg",
           "url_170x135":"https:\/\/img0.etsystatic.com\/015\/0\/7566894\/il_170x135.410447372_sjo4.jpg",
           "url_570xN":"https:\/\/img0.etsystatic.com\/015\/0\/7566894\/il_570xN.410447372_sjo4.jpg",
           "url_fullxfull":"https:\/\/img0.etsystatic.com\/015\/0\/7566894\/il_fullxfull.410447372_sjo4.jpg",
           "full_height":737,
           "full_width":600
        },
        {
           "listing_image_id":402927400,
           "hex_code":"897761",
           "red":137,
           "green":119,
           "blue":97,
           "hue":33,
           "saturation":29,
           "brightness":53,
           "is_black_and_white":false,
           "creation_tsz":1356746394,
           "listing_id":118973432,
           "rank":2,
           "url_75x75":"https:\/\/img0.etsystatic.com\/003\/0\/7566894\/il_75x75.402927400_e80x.jpg",
           "url_170x135":"https:\/\/img0.etsystatic.com\/003\/0\/7566894\/il_170x135.402927400_e80x.jpg",
           "url_570xN":"https:\/\/img0.etsystatic.com\/003\/0\/7566894\/il_570xN.402927400_e80x.jpg",
           "url_fullxfull":"https:\/\/img0.etsystatic.com\/003\/0\/7566894\/il_fullxfull.402927400_e80x.jpg",
           "full_height":800,
           "full_width":986
        },
        {
           "listing_image_id":402923983,
           "hex_code":"C8C1C0",
           "red":200,
           "green":193,
           "blue":192,
           "hue":8,
           "saturation":4,
           "brightness":78,
           "is_black_and_white":false,
           "creation_tsz":1356746394,
           "listing_id":118973432,
           "rank":3,
           "url_75x75":"https:\/\/img1.etsystatic.com\/005\/0\/7566894\/il_75x75.402923983_snri.jpg",
           "url_170x135":"https:\/\/img1.etsystatic.com\/005\/0\/7566894\/il_170x135.402923983_snri.jpg",
           "url_570xN":"https:\/\/img1.etsystatic.com\/005\/0\/7566894\/il_570xN.402923983_snri.jpg",
           "url_fullxfull":"https:\/\/img1.etsystatic.com\/005\/0\/7566894\/il_fullxfull.402923983_snri.jpg",
           "full_height":440,
           "full_width":640
        }
     ]
  }
   ],
   "params":{
  "limit":"1",
  "offset":0,
  "page":null,
  "shop_id":"imjustsayininc",
  "keywords":null,
  "sort_on":"created",
  "sort_order":"down",
  "min_price":null,
  "max_price":null,
  "color":null,
  "color_accuracy":0,
  "tags":null,
  "category":null,
  "translate_keywords":"false",
  "include_private":0
   },
   "type":"Listing",
   "pagination":{
  "effective_limit":1,
  "effective_offset":0,
  "next_offset":1,
  "effective_page":1,
  "next_page":2
   }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is pull all values from the image field where it shows an image URL (url_75x75,url_170x135,url_570xN & url_fullxfull).

I seem to be stuck only on the importing of the images. They seems to be in an array and I can't figure out how to implement pulling them like I do the rest of the content.

I've spent roughly 3 days searching, trying and failing at doing this.

I was successful when I had the Json request split up into separate requests but recently learned I could include images into one JSON request which is the method I am currently trying.

How can I do this?

I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm even newer at JSON so please be descriptive as possible and try not to overload me with complex ways I could do this, thank you.

Comment: Your question title is one thing, the question in your text is completely different and your JSON doesn't match your description (you have image URLs, not images) - can you be a bit clearer about what the problem is?

Comment: I just edited the title after reviewing my question, I apologize. I am wanting to save the "url_*x*" values to variables. I am unable to implement this into my foreach.

Comment: You get an error or it's just not inserting?

Comment: The error I get is:
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/theendst/public_html    /mysite.com/etsyapi/etsyapi/include/pull_listing_data.php on line 18

Also this isn't the full code, this is the foreach I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` is an array of objects, so is `Images`

I didn't test it but I think something like this should be able to retrieve the first image of the first result:

```
$product->results[0]->Images[0]->url_75x75
```

In your code, this is obviously wrong:

```
$product->results.Images[url_75x75]
```

Javascript with PHP syntax mixed together? ;-)

Comment: There's sill no results for the image url in my database. It's like the code doesn't see any value in object?

Comment: Ah, you're not using PHP5.4?

Comment: Capsule,

I played around with your answer and it turns out:
 `$product->Images[0]->url_75x75`
was the right way to do this, thank you and everyone else who responded to my question! :)

Comment: Ah yeah in my example $product is the decoded JSON object